# Nodejs Passport Auto login works on Chrome but not Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, safari, passport.js

My angularJs application is not working the way as it should.

Here is the problem:

- When I open Safari browser and logging into my account.
- After using the site when I closed the instance of the browser and returning back on it.
- Safari is asking me to login again.

Whereas the above defined case is working fine in the case of other browsers like Chrome.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What code do you have? Please show it.

Comment: Thank You everyone....it works for me....issue is with the cookie...maxAge was set to null...now i increased the maxage val and it worked for me...But I am still confused how the stuff is working fine for other browsers like chrome  :P...